# Bodyfitness vs bikini fitness - genetics

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, gym

It is known that a lot can be done with the body, but are there any specific genetic conditions that allow you to choose a proper category in bodybuilding? I'm a bit confused by the category bodyfitness vs bikini fitness. While bikini fitness contestants tend to be more hourglass shape, the bodyfitness ones are more into V-like silhouette. Although, when you look at figure / bodyfitness and bikini fitness, it's sometimes hard to tell a difference.

Is there a way to tell at the beginning which way to go? When you're naturally a woman with broader shoulders is it better to try figure and when you're the smaller one with rather harmonic body shape you're prone to be successful in bikini division? Or there is no rule? I find it hard to distinguish between these two categories.

Comment: There's no real rule, judging preferences change over time, and people change categories depending on current conditions (internalized and external). If the goal is competition, I'd say evaluate current physique against current top 10-20 in the categories of interest and see how it compares--but that doesn't necessarily provide much info. Go for whichever you want!

Comment: You can always focus your training to improve your weak points for the specific category you want.

Answer (score 1):

A coach / trainer should be able to give you the most honest opinion based on pictures or live.  There are specific conditioning, shape, development, etc - that are more like one category versus the other. especially if your looking to compete, being in the correct class is very important.